# How to stop execution of for loop in middle in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsoperationqueue

Hi in my application i have two types of syncs. 1.Auto sync 2.Manual Sync. In both the syncs i am downloding a bunch of files from server. If I choose auto sync all files will get download.

Code is like this

```
for(int i=0;i<filescount;i++)
{

[self downloadfiles];

}

-(void)download files
{
   //Here i am creating `NSInvocationOperation`.

      if(!synchingfilecount)
         totalreceiveddata=0;
}
```

Based on totalreceiveddata I am updating progress bar. Now the issue is if it autosync it is working fine.While downloading files using autosync and in middle if i click manual sync that time `[self downloadfiles];` method will get called but the issue is synchingfilescount is not updating immediately it's completeing the autosyncfiles download and synchingfilescount become 0 due to this reason totalreceiveddata become 0 and progress bar is disappearing. After complete this opertiona again synchingfilecount becomes 4 but i cannot able to see the progress  bar due to above situation. Please any one help me how can I come out from this situation.

Comment: your question heading is completely wrong dude !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you need to create some flags so that you can manage the flow of your code. You can do this by making a boolean property and setting it as you need in the completion block of these sync methods. That way you can call a method or only execute a method after the call is complete.

Comment: Hi wilson thanks for your reply. small change in requirement that is when ever i click on manual sync I have to stop auto sync and have to start manual sync.Can you please let me know how can i accomplish this.

Comment: What happens in your auto sync? @user3341324 if its just one network call, you cannot stop it mid call but you can just discard the results no problem .

Comment: Hi Wilson yes I can stop autosync immediately. Now I have to start only manual sync. Auto sync we can stop.

Comment: Cool. so what is your question. do you have it figured out?